# Newtonsoft Json version issue while implementing Azure key vault 2.0

Tags: c#, azure, json.net, azure-blob-storage, azure-keyvault

I am trying to implement azure key vault encryption in an existing application but facing newtonsoft.json version hell problem.

The existing application reference to newtonsoft version 4.5.0.0 but while i am trying to use the Microsoft.Azure.keyVault version 2.0 it required newtonsoft.json version of 6.0.0.0

I can not change the existing newtonsoft version to 6.0.0.0 as it is raising error in the existing code at runtime and they don't want to change the code either(the other team).

So, What's the best way to deal with it?

which version of Azure Key Vault to use so we don't required to change the existing newtonSoft.Json version of 4.5?

Comment: If it's causing you serous issue, you should persuade the other team to collaborate.  However, depending on how much change it has, you could try binding redirect or try doing something in a separate `AppDomain` may help

Comment: Can you use a binding redirect?

Comment: @mjwills, tried but no use.

Answer (score 0):

> which version of Azure Key Vault to use so we don't required to change the existing newtonSoft.Json version of 4.5?

There is no version of Azure Key Vault that could be compatible with  newtonSoft.Json version 4.5. It has constraint with newtonsoft.json(>=6.0.8)

> What's the best way to deal with it?

In your case if the version of newtonsoft.json can't be changed, I recommond you to use [Azure Key Vault api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/).